# while loop in ADA83

Tags: file-io, while-loop, ada

I have written the following code in Ada83 to find the size of a file:

```
with Text_IO;
use Text_IO;

procedure imp3ada is

package Int_IO is new Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer);
use Int_IO;

inputFile: File_Type;
i: integer:=0;
fileSize: Integer:=0;
fileCurrentPosition: Integer:=0;

begin
    open(inputFile, In_File, "test.cfg");
        while not End_of_File(inputFile) loop
        fileCurrentPosition:=fileCurrentPosition+1;
        end loop;
    fileSize:=fileCurrentPosition;
    Int_IO.put(fileCurrentPosition);
    Int_IO.put(fileSize);
    close(inputFile);
end imp3ada;
```

The code compiles well but when i try to run it nothing happens II expect it to print number of characters in the file. I guess it is going into an infinite loop. Can someone help me with where it went wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find the size of a file in arbitrary units, you can instantiate [`Direct_IO`](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-14-02.html#14.2) using some suitable type and call the `SIZE` function. In outline,

```
with Direct_IO;
…
package DIO is new Direct_IO(Character);
F: DIO.File_Type;
Size: Integer;
…
DIO.Open(F, DIO.In_File, Name);
Size := Integer(DIO.Size(F));
DIO.Close(F);
```

Addendum: See also

- [*Ada83 & Ada 95 Compatibility*](http://archive.adaic.com/intro/tech/8395comp.html)
- [*GNAT User's Guide: Appendix E Compatibility and Porting Guide*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gnat_ugn_unw/Compatibility-and-Porting-Guide.html#Compatibility-and-Porting-Guide)

Addendum: *I am supposed to write a parser for simple configuration files.*

For parsing configurataion, you can read the file [`Line_By_Line`](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#Ada). In that way, you don't need to know the length of the file in advance. Once you have a `Line`, you can index the component characters as shown in [§3.6.3. The Type String](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-03-06.html#3.6.3).

Comment: Definitely the best way. It would have been my answer, except I didn't know if that applied to Ada-83...

Comment: This does not work for Ada83 while i need something in Ada83 alone.
it gives me the error:

Direct_IO undefined and DIO undefined.

Comment: It *should* apply to Ada-83 as I now understand, and according to "Ada Language and Methodology" (Watt, Wichmann & Findlay). Do you have a missing With or Use clause?

Comment: The package is in the Ada 83 LRM: http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-14-02.html#14.2.5

Comment: @user3435894: I've added a `with` clause and some potentially useful references. Are you learning, maintaining or porting?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have included both With and Use clauses. But I still get the same error. Could it be a machine fault?
I am running it on Ubuntu 13.10 on VM Virtual machine.

Comment: @user3435894: Please edit your question to show your current approach and the exact error you get; it may help to identify your compiler.

Comment: At this point it's looking like a faulty compiler installation (e.g. missing libraries? or Debian/Ubuntu multilib path error) is a possibility. So -which compiler, which version?

Comment: Or possibly a limitation of using `-gnat83` with GNAT.

Comment: @trashgod I am learning Ada. I am supposed to write a parser for simple configuration files. And yes, I have used the -gnat83 flag with gnat. This is to ensure that none of the Ada95 features are supported I suppose. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3435894: For parsing configurataion, I'd go [`Line_By_Line`](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#Ada); then you don't need to know the length of the file in advance.

Comment: Thanks, will take that. Also can you give me a little more clue on the work? Like how exactly do I manipulate Line by line?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current approach, or consider posing a new question based on your current understanding; more above.

Answer (score 3):

fileCurrentPosition is just an integer with no relationship to the current position in the file. As you aren't doing anything to advance through the file, it will just increment forever as you observed..

Perhaps you wanted to get a character each time round the loop? 
In which case you may want to call the "Get" function...

Another point to note : if it's an Integer file, Get will return an Integer, so you will count the integers in the file, not characters... If you want to count characters in a file, you probably need to use Text_IO not Int_IO.

EDIT : as Jacob points out, calling `Text_IO.Get` in the loop would not accurately count the characters in the file, but exclude line termination characters. This makes sense for many applications; allowing you to abstract for example over systems with different sequences for "end of line" such as Unix/Windows.

To accurately count characters (or bytes) in a file, you could instantiate the generic `Sequential_IO` package for character (or a suitable definition of "byte") and loop as above, extracting characters via `Read` (not `Get`) and counting them until `End_Of_File`.

Comment: Using Text_IO packages for the problem is not a good idea as the problem is posed.  Reading characters is likely to skip line and page breaks and mis-process the end of the file.  Reading integers will only work if 1) the file only contains integers and 2) the "size of the file" is defined to mean the number of integers in it.

Comment: @Jacob : good points; I'd delete the answer but it's probably worth leaving to show why *not* to do it this way.

Comment: I would urge you to update your answer to incorporate @JacobSparreAndersen's caveats. We still don't know the question's genesis, and your answer regarding the loop may provide the critical insight.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question as posed, Your loop:

```
    while not End_of_File(inputFile) loop
      fileCurrentPosition:=fileCurrentPosition+1;
    end loop;
```

Does not manipulate the file type anywhere. Therefore the EOF will not be reached. Ever. This is your infinite loop.

If you add a call to :

```
procedure Get(File : in  File_Type; Item : out Character);
```

You should actually traverse the file character by character and exit the loop on EOF.

Caveat: Not actually tested this at all!